# How to enable Multiple,Independant working copies in Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm sure there might be a documentation on this, but i'm just unable to find it. When i right click and choose SVN checkout, i see an option called "Multiple,Independent working copies grayed out. How do i enable it?

Version: TortoiseSVN 1.8.4, Build 24972 64 bit file.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option "Multipe, independent working copies" becomes availble after you enter multiple URLs in "URL of repository" field. You can enter multiple URLs and separate them with asterisk * character. E.g. `http://server/"svn1/*http://server/svn2`

Here is the option's tooltip:

> Don't make the checkout directory a sparse working copy. Instead, all
>   URLs get checked out into a separate\nworking copies next to each
>   other. This works for directory URLs only.